# Why do I get different heteroscedasticity robust standard errors in R when using the plm package?

Tags: r, robust, panel-data, heteroscedasticity, fixed-effects-model

I am now writing my bachelors thesis and I have come across some difficulties. I am about to do some panel regressions with time and entity fixed effects and I would therefore like to use the plm package. But when I do add fixed effects and want to have heteroscedasticity robust standard errors they seem to be incorrect.

Does anyone know why the HC standard errors differ?

Here is my code

```
# Load data
load(file="panel")
attach(panel)

# Load packages
library(lmtest)
library(plm)


# Create two models. The lm.model is a linear model and as the
# LAND variable is a factor variable representing countries
# (Land = Country in Swedish) this model will have entity fixed
# effects. In the plm.model the plm package is used and
# individual effects and within model is turned on (which is
# the same as entity fixed effects)
lm.model<-lm(NETTOSPARANDE ~ EURO + LAND, data=panel)
plm.model<-plm(NETTOSPARANDE ~ EURO, index=c("LAND","ÅR"), effect="individual", model="within", data=panel)

# When looking at the coefficents without heteroscadisity robust
# standard errors they are identical. They do also have the same
# value in stata.
coeftest(lm.model)[1:2,]
coeftest(plm.model)

# But when looking at the coefficents using heteroscadisity
# robust standard errors the lm.model and the plm.model produces
# different standard errors.
coeftest(lm.model, vcov.=vcovHC(lm.model, method="white2", type="HC1"))[1:2,]
coeftest(plm.model, vcov.=vcovHC(plm.model, method="white2", type="HC1"))
```

If you want to test the data it can be found here (the panel file)
  [1]: https://sourceforge.net/projects/emumoralhazard/files/ *R-data*

And here is my output

```
1> # Load data
1> load(file="panel")

1> attach(panel)

1> # Load packages
1> library(lmtest)
Loading required package: zoo

1> library(plm)
Loading required package: kinship
Loading required package: survival
Loading required package: splines
Loading required package: nlme
Loading required package: lattice
[1] "kinship is loaded"
Loading required package: Formula
Loading required package: MASS
Loading required package: sandwich

1> # Create two models. The lm.model is a linear model and as the
1> # LAND variabel is a factor variable representing countries
1> # (Land = Country in swedish) this model will have entity fixed
1> # effects. In the plm.model the plm package is used and
1> # individual effects and within model is turned on (which is
1> # the same as entity fixed effects)
1> lm.model<-lm(NETTOSPARANDE ~ EURO + LAND, data=panel)

1> plm.model<-plm(NETTOSPARANDE ~ EURO, index=c("LAND","ÅR"), effect="individual", model="within", data=panel)

1> # When looking at the coefficients without heteroscedasticity robust
1> # standard errors they are identical. They do also have the same
1> # value in Stata.
1> coeftest(lm.model)[1:2,]
             Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) -3.731024  0.7731778 -4.825570 1.726921e-06
EURO1        2.187170  0.4076720  5.365024 1.112984e-07

1> coeftest(plm.model)

t test of coefficients:

      Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
EURO1  2.18717    0.40767   5.365 1.113e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 


1> # But when looking at the coefficients using heteroscedasticity 
1> # robust standard errors the lm.model and the plm.model produces
1> # different standard errors.
1> coeftest(lm.model, vcov.=vcovHC(lm.model, method="white2", type="HC1"))[1:2,]
             Estimate Std. Error    t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) -3.731024  0.3551280 -10.506138 5.102122e-24
EURO1        2.187170  0.3386029   6.459395 2.009894e-10

1> coeftest(plm.model, vcov.=vcovHC(plm.model, method="white2", type="HC1"))

t test of coefficients:

      Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
EURO1  2.18717    0.33849  6.4615 1.983e-10 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Answer (score 7):

Though numerically both of your model coefficients estimates coincide, you are actually fitting two different models: least square dummy variables and fixed effects.
They differ on their assumptions, so the robust standard errors are calculated differently.

Function `vcovHC` is a wrapper function, different functions are actually used in case of `lm` model and `plm`. In the first case the function `vcovHC` comes from the `sandwich` package, in the second from the `plm` package.

The difference in results arises because  `vcovHC` for `lm` object does not exploit panel data structure. Comparing

```
plm:::vcovHC.plm
```

and

```
vcovHC.default
```

reveals that for panel data there is additional argument `cluster = c("group", "time")`.

Look into [Wooldridge book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262232588) for more explanation why least squares dummy variables and fixed effects regressions differ. It has whole chapter dedicated for that.

Comment: Thank you for the answear.
But is the first model pooled? I have added the LAND term wich is the entity dummy variable (as it's a facor variable.
And as I can se the parameter estimates (EURO) are identical?

Comment: @Skolnick, I've missed that at first, so I changed my answer accordingly

Comment: I have tried to get reach of that book but the library has a copy that's not available for the moment. But I can perhaps ask which model that has the most accurate standard errors when HC-robust, LSDV or within?

Answer (score -1):

@Skolnick -
After an admittedly quick look at your problem, it seems that plm() truncates and/or rounds results to less digits than lm().  I think this is the most likely cause of the differences in your heteroscedasticity-robust standard error estimates.  Explore summary(plm.model) and summary(lm.model) for differences in residual quantiles.