# Difference between coeftest output: 'twoways' and 'individual' + time dummies

Tags: r, panel-data, standard-error, fixed-effects-model, clustered-standard-errors

Cross-posted on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68925694/difference-between-coeftest-output-twoways-and-individual-time-dummies

I am currently working with panel data and I want to adjust the standard errors such that they are robust and clustered by group. When doing so, I encountered a particularity of the `coeftest()` function that I do not understand.

In particular, when estimating a fixed-effects model using `plm()` with the option `'twoways'` and then using `coeftest()` to get the correct standard errors, I get different standard errors as compared to using `plm()` and the option `'individual'` while including time dummies. The estimates of the coefficients and the not-clustered, not-robust standard errors are identical. From my understanding the adjusted standard errors should be equivalent as well. What causes this difference? Which standard errors are 'correct'? Below is a reproducible example.

````
library(plm)
library(lmtest)
library(haven)
library(fastDummies)

panel_data <- read_dta("http://dss.princeton.edu/training/Panel101.dta")
panel_data <- pdata.frame(panel_data, index = c("country","year"), drop.index = FALSE)
panel_data <- dummy_cols(panel_data, select_columns = 'year')

pmodel_1_formula <- as.formula("y ~ x1 + x2 + x3")
pmodel_1 <- plm(pmodel_1_formula,
                data = panel_data,
                model = 'within',
                effect = 'twoways')

summary(pmodel_1)
coeftest(pmodel_1, vcov=vcovHC(pmodel_1, type="HC1", cluster="group"))

pmodel_2_formula <- as.formula(paste("y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 +",  paste(colnames(panel_data[10:19]), collapse = '+')))
pmodel_2 <- plm(pmodel_2_formula,
                data = panel_data,
                model = 'within', 
                effect = 'individual')

summary(pmodel_2)
coeftest(pmodel_2, vcov=vcovHC(pmodel_2, type="HC1", cluster="group"))
```
````

Comment: Is this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6141/why-do-i-get-different-heteroscedasticity-robust-standard-errors-in-r-when-using) helpful?

Comment: Hi Thomas, thank you for the reply. I believe the post is related, however, it appears that the difference in the problem you linked to comes from using ```lm``` and ```plm```, whereas I use ```plm``` in both cases. What is insightful is that robust standard errors seem to be calculated differently depending on an inclusion of time dummies or demeaning. Would you happen to have a reference that links to this issue? I saw that in the post you linked they cite the Wooldridge book, however, I could not find a chapter on the difference in robust standard errors.